# React Hooks missing dependency with function passed from parent to child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I have this type of situation in my current React (v17.0.2) project that gives me 'React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency onTogglePopup' warning.

I need to pass a shared function from parent component to child component and there add an  event listener to window when component 'mounts'. It currently does what I want but I believe there must be a better way to accomplish the same *and* make the linter happy.
I can neither include the function into dependency array nor remove the empty array since I'd loose the functionality.
How do I solve this situation properly without any anti-patterns, hacks or just plain hiding of linter warnings?

```
const App = ()=>{
   const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);

   const onTogglePopup = ()=>{
      setShowPopup(prev => !prev);
      // do more App-related stuff here
   }

   return(
      <main>
         {/* other elements */}
         {showPopup && <Popup onTogglePopup={onTogglePopup}/> }
      </main>
   )
}

const Popup = ({onTogglePopup})=>{
   
   useEffect(()=>{
       const onKeyDown = ev =>{
           if (ev.key === 'Escape') onTogglePopup(); // the problem spot
       }

       window.addEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
       
       // remove kbd listener on unmount
       return ()=>{
           window.removeEventListener('keydown', onKeyDown);
       }
   },[]);
   
   return createPortal(
      <aside id="popup">...
   )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can memoize `onTogglePopup` function *before* passing it to the child component as a prop.

To memoize the function, use the `useCallback` hook as shown below:

```
const onTogglePopup = useCallback(() => {
  setShowPopup(prev => !prev);
  // do more App-related stuff here
}, []);
```

Doing this will allow you to safely specify this function in the dependency array of the `useEffect` hook without causing unnecessary execution of the `useEffect` hook's callback function every time the parent component re-renders.

---

**Note:** `useCallback` hook also has a dependency array, so you need to be careful not to omit any of its dependencies to avoid the problems because of stale closure.

In your case, if `setShowPopup` is the only dependency of the `useCallback` hook, it can be included or excluded without any problem because `setShowPopup` is a state setter function whose reference is guaranteed to never change.

Comment: I really appreciate the note part too! I did not know that the state setters are guaranteed to never change. Any recommended links where I could read more about this? It seems my knowledge is not in-depth enough.

Comment: Reacts docs have all the necessary information: [React Docs - Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate).

Answer (score 0):

In `App`, instead of this:

```js
   const onTogglePopup = ()=>{
      setShowPopup(prev => !prev);
      // do more App-related stuff here
   }
```

Use this:

```js
   const onTogglePopup = useCallback(()=>{
      setShowPopup(prev => !prev);
      // do more App-related stuff here
   }, [setShowPopup]);
```

`useCallback` preserves the reference to the function unless dependencies change, so you don't trigger `useEffect` every render.